# Functional Limit Definition Proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am wondering if there is a way to prove the following functional limit, only by definition.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3}(1/x)=1/3$

Currently, my proof involves proving separately that lim 3-x goes to 0 and lim 3x goes to 9 as x goes to 3. Then, I use the Algebraic Theorem for Functional limits to prove to original proposition. Again, the question is simply, how might I do this without the Theorem? Is that possible?

Comment: It is always possible for such simple cases.

Comment: Do you have a hint?

Comment: $$\left| \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{3} \right| = \frac{|x-3|}{3|x|} = \frac{\mbox{small}}{\mbox{bounded away from $0$}} = \mbox{small}$$ now pick $\delta = \min \{ \varepsilon , 1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $|x-3|<\delta \implies |1/x-1/3|<\epsilon$

$|x-3|<\delta \implies 3-\delta <x<3+\delta$

let $\delta = \min(1,6\epsilon)$

x > 2

$|1/x-1/3|<\delta/6\leq\epsilon$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it is that |x-3|<d implies |1/x - 1/3|<epsilon? The connection to the choice of delta is not all that clear to me.

Comment: |1/x - 1/3| = |(x-3)/3x|,  |x-3|<delta ==> x>2 and |1/x - 1/3| < delta / 6

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.